# I need help to reorder array.object considering a specific element

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I have this `array.object` and I need to reorder it so that if it has an empty `displayOrder` it will be last considering the type.

```js
[
  {
    "displayOrder": "",
    "type": "moment",
  },
  {
    "displayOrder": "2",
    "type": "moment",
  },
  {
    "displayOrder": "4",
    "type": "moment",
  },
  {
    "displayOrder": "1",
    "type": "presentation",
  }
]
```

//Reorder to this:

```js
[

  {
    "displayOrder": "2",
    "type": "moment",
  },
  {
    "displayOrder": "4",
    "type": "moment",
  },
  {
    "displayOrder": "",
    "type": "moment",
  },
  {
    "displayOrder": "1",
    "type": "presentation",
  }
]
```

What could I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain what you need, you can simply specifying a function and pass it to the [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#comparefn) method. I've tried something along this line, but you can adapt it according to your needs.

```js
let array = [
    {
        "displayOrder": "",
        "type": "moment",
    },
    {
        "displayOrder": "2",
        "type": "moment",
    },
    {
        "displayOrder": "4",
        "type": "moment",
    },
    {
        "displayOrder": "1",
        "type": "presentation",
    }
];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.type === b.type) {
        if (b.displayOrder === '') return -1;
        if (a.displayOrder === '') return 1;
        return Number(a.displayOrder) > Number(b.displayOrder) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    if (a.type !== b.type) return (a.type < b.type) ? -1 : 1;
    return (a.displayOrder < b.displayOrder) ? -1 : (a.displayOrder > b.displayOrder) ? 0 : 1;
});

console.log(array);
```